# simplicity of G

Tags: finite-groups, simple-groups

I took an exam today. If I remember correctly question was like this:
let G be a group. if it has "a" element which has **exact** two conjugates, then G cant be simple.

I answered:
let that two conjugates be $g_1a{g_1^{-1}} $and ${g_2}a{g_2^{-1}}$
and H= {a}. 
then N(H) ={g:$gag^{-1}\in G$}={$g_1,g_2$}
so $|H|=1 and|N(H)|=2$

since $[N(H):H]=2$ then $H \triangleleft N(H)$...
$H<N(H)<G $ 
so G has a normal group, therefor G cant be simple.

was my answer correct?

Comment: Why is H normal in N(H) ? Is H a subgroup ?

Comment: I forgot the word "exact". now hasnt N:(H) only have $g_1,g_2$?

Comment: Does "exactly two conjugates" mean two conjugates besides $a$ itself, or two conjugates including $a$?

Comment: I meant there are only two conjugates of a in G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of conjugates of a does not have to be equal to N({a}) in size. It might happen that x,y belong to N({a}) ($x,y$ distinct) and $xax^-1$=$yay^-1$

The proof that G is not simple is:

We consider G/N({a}). Note that |G/N(H)|=2

Proof: Consider the function that sends the coset xN({a}) to xax^-1 , this function is a bijection.

If N(H) were equal to G then |G/N(H)|=1. Thus N({a}) is a proper normal subgroup of G